# Does the original Everquest still require a monthly subscription?

Tags: everquest

Does Everquest still have a monthly fee? What are the exact details on it?

(I tried to Google this, but kept getting back EQ2 news about it going free and nothing about EQ1)

Comment: The start date is 16 March 2012. http://eqplayers.station.sony.com/news_article.vm?id=524201&month=022012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in March, 2012, the original Everquest will be going "free to play" and the subscription fee will be optional.  However, at this point they are ending support for the Macintosh version of the game.

The free to play version has fewer features than the version with a monthly fee.  You can read more about the differences in the [free to play FAQ](http://www.everquest.com/free/).

Up until this annoucement, it cost about $15 per month to play the original Everquest.

Comment: few more weeks, then f2p.

Answer (score 4):

In March 2012, [EQ vanilla will become F2P](http://eqplayers.station.sony.com/news_article.vm?id=524183&month=012012).

> After listening to your feedback and suggestions over the past few
>   years, I'm happy to announce that in early March 2012, EverQuest will
>   be going free-to-play.

Comment: They only milked it for 12 years :)